# Can't connect to server with port opened via Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Docker container that runs with `--net=host` and binds directly to the host's port 7000 and 9042 on GCE. Here's my `netstat` on the VM:

```
$ netstat -tulpn

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 <vm-private-ip>:9042           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 <vm-private-ip>:7000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
[...etc..]
```

However VMs from the same network cannot connect to this VM via the port 7000 or 9042. What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you share the answer to these questions?
1. What are the program that is running from docker for those ports
2. How to access it locally in docker for app testing.
3. How do you access other VM using the port

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the port is configured to open inside docker configuration. However, VPC firewall can also play a big role in this concern.

I suggest creating a firewall rule to open port 7000 and 9042 in your VPC network. You can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#console) as a guidance for firewall rule creation.